# SOQL NEXT_N_DAYS Query not working

Tags: soql, query

The below query doesn't return any results

```
select Phone__c from Application__c where Orientation_Date__c < NEXT_N_DAYS:8 and Orientation_Date__c > NEXT_N_DAYS:1
```

But the next query returns 2 records with `Orientation_Date__c` `2017-07-27` and `2017-07-28`

```
select Phone__c from Application__c where Orientation_Date__c > NEXT_N_DAYS:1
```

Today is `2017-07-25` so these 2 records should meet the criteria for the first query right? Why aren't they being returned?

Comment: You say that it does return records with those dates. The behavior you describe is correct. Can you clarify what you observe versus what you expect?

Comment: I expect the top query to also return those records that the second query returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on [`Date Literals`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

> **Date Literal**
> NEXT_N_DAYS:n
>
> **Range**
> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for the next n days.
>
> **Example**
> SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate > NEXT_N_DAYS:15

Since the range starts from midnight today, **using `< NEXT_N_DAYS:n` is equivalent to `< TODAY`**.

Unfortunately, unlike `N_DAYS_AGO:n`, there does not appear to be any sort of `N_DAYS_FROM_NOW:n` literal, so I'm not sure if there is a workaround in pure SOQL. Your best bet might be to create a formula for `Days_From_Now__c` and filter on that instead.

Comment: I love salesforce